# Do any two nonzero real numbers behave the same under subtraction?

Tags: model-theory

This is similar to my previous model theory question, here: [Regarding the theory of real addition with a nonzero constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359185/regarding-the-theory-of-real-addition-with-a-nonzero-constant).  Let $r$ and $s$ be any two nonzero real numbers, and consider the structures $(\mathbb{R};-,r)$ and $(\mathbb{R};-,s)$, where $-$ is the binary operation of subtraction. Are those two structures isomorphic?

Comment: Have you tried using the ideas of the answer to that question to address this one? It's not hard to do so ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber So, the same isomorphism from that question works on this one, also?